# 1601/01/01 of lastLogonTimeStamp attribute

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, ldap

I'm using lastLogonTimeStamp to track the users last logon time as the following code:

```
$Domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$ADSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$ADSearch.SearchRoot ="LDAP://$Domain"
$ADSearch.SearchScope = "subtree"
$ADSearch.PageSize = 100
$ADSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=user)"

$properies = @("distinguishedName",
"sAMAccountName",
"mail",
"lastLogonTimeStamp")

foreach ($pro in $properies) {
    $ADSearch.PropertiesToLoad.add($pro)   
}

$userObjects = $ADSearch.FindAll()
foreach ($user  in $userObjects) {
    $logon = $user.Properties.Item("lastLogonTimeStamp")[0]
    $lastLogon = [datetime]::fromfiletime($logon)        
    $lastLogon= $lastLogon.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
    $lastLogon
}
```

I've gotten so far:

```
1601/01/01
1601/01/01
3/12/2012
1601/01/01
3/19/2015
```

This is not the first time I'm bloody confused about the *1601/01/01* value. And I've read also the MS document about this value and for me it's nonsense, it does not describe much what is the purposes of it. Not only `lastLogonTimeStamp` has this output, many other attributes have return this as well. So my questions are:

1. What is the purpose of this value?
2. In this case, what should I return as a proper human readable output ? (This attribute is not valid for this user?)

Comment: What is `$user` here ?? How are you getting the value?

Comment: @RanadipDutta Edited

Comment: A value of `1601/01/01 00:00:00` basically means "this timestamp value has not been set (yet)". It's Microsoft's equivalent of NULL for timestamps. WRT to the `lastLogonTimestamp` attribute it means "this user has never logged on".

Comment: 01/01/1601 corresponds to a filetime timestamp of 0, indicating that the user in question has never logged on

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank so much guys :). Now I can be sure what I should put there.

Comment: @Ender: Mathias and Ansgar both explained your answer clearly.

Comment: @RanadipDutta yeah, feel so good after getting it clear :)

Comment: @Ender, while you have got an answer to your question, I do want to mention, that the field `lastLogonTimeStamp` is not intended to give you the last login time of the user.  From Microsoft's blog: _It is important to note that the intended purpose of the lastLogontimeStamp attribute to help identify inactive computer and user accounts. The lastLogon attribute is not designed to provide real time logon information. With default settings in place the lastLogontimeStamp will be 9-14 days behind the current date._

Comment: Here is the [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/)

Comment: @Burzum I don't need exactly when they logon, I just need approximate values (recently is good enough). There are two attributes here: `lastLogonTimeStamp` and `lastLogon`. In order to determine if a user or computer account has recently logged onto the domain I should user `lastLogonTimeStamp` rather than `lastLogon`. I have read the article you have atm. tks for answering

Comment: @Ender in that case you can use lastLogonTimeStamp.

Answer (score 6):

There is a known bug with the "last logon timestamp" and Windows 2016 domain controllers.

LDAP simple bind are not updating the last logon timestamp like previous OS ( 2012, 2008 ). Be careful.

I spent 2 months with MS on this. A patch will be released eventually... but for now it's not fixed.

Comment: Thanks, Friend. I lost a lot of time trying to do this work .. I tested it in my old ActiveDirectory and its worked fine.

Comment: Yes, good find - do you have a ticket reference or KB article as we are having same problem and want to raise it with MS (the more people that do so, the more important they will treat it I hope)

Comment: @pascal, what was the KB or the patch to apply to fix this issue?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer this is it: September 20, 2018 - KB4457127 / OS Build 14393.2517
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-lastlogontimestamp-is-not-updated-after-you-perform-an-ldap-simple-bind-operation-in-windows-server-2016-4bbbb80c-dc67-4817-be80-33b9f2d6d4e1

Comment: Thanks, @IoannisDrositis appreciate it very muchly.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/be6ee391-c98a-4192-b9c6-416aff32f2f7/lastlogontimestamp-again?forum=winserverDS#be6ee391-c98a-4192-b9c6-416aff32f2f7 this URL explains everything in details